# ExpressionEngine templates: pass a plugin/module's output as parameter to another plugin/module

Tags: templates, expressionengine

Here's basically what I want to accomplish:

```
{exp:plugin1:method arg="{exp:plugin2:method}"}
```

I’ve tried a number of different approaches.

### Approach 1:

```
{exp:plugin1:method arg="{exp:plugin2:method}"}
```

**Result:** `Plugin1->method`’s `arg` parameter value is the string, `{exp:plugin2:method}`, and it’s never parsed.

### Approach 2:

My understanding of the parsing order suggests that this might have different results, but apparently it does not.

```
{preload_replace:replaced="{exp:plugin2:method}"}
{exp:plugin1:method arg="{replaced}"}
```

**Result:** The `arg` parameter has the same value as approach 1.

### Approach 3:

First I define a snippet (`snip`), whose content is:

```
{exp:plugin2:method}
```

Then in the template:

```
{exp:plugin1:method arg="{snip}"}
```

**Result:** Same as approaches 1 and 2.

### Approach 4:

Noting that plugins are processed in the order they appear, I have even tested simply placing an instance of `{exp:plugin2:method}` before the `{exp:plugin1:method}` call. My thinking is that I could wrap this first call in a regex replacement plugin in order to suppress output, but that it would trigger Plugin2’s parsing first.

```
{exp:plugin2:method}
{exp:plugin1:method arg="{exp:plugin2:method}"}
```

**Result:** `Plugin1->method`’s `arg` parameter value is the temporary hash placeholder for `Plugin2->method`’s output (MD5 I believe) that the Template class reserves until later.

Comment: FYI: The EE focused SE site is now in public beta if you want to post future EE questions there: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround, but I'll wait a while to see if a better solution comes up before I accept my own answer. The workaround is to wrap `plugin1` with `plugin2` and replace template tags referring to its methods within the `tagdata`. Note that this requires a `parse="inward"` parameter on the `plugin2` call.

### In the template:

```
{exp:plugin2 parse="inward"}
    {exp:plugin1:method arg="{someplugin2method}"}
{/exp:plugin2}
```

### In the plugin class:

```
static $public_methods;

function __construct() {
    // Actual construction code omitted...

    if(($tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata) !== false && trim($tagdata) !== '') {
        if(!isset(self::$public_methods)) {
            self::$public_methods = array();
            $methods = get_class_methods($this);
            foreach($methods as $method) {
                if($method == get_class($this) || $method == '__construct') {
                    continue;
                }
                $reflection = new ReflectionMethod(get_class($this), $method);
                if($reflection->isPublic()) {
                    self::$public_methods[] = $method;
                }
            }

            self::$public_methods = implode('|', self::$public_methods);
        }

        $tagdata = preg_replace_callback('/\{(' . self::$public_methods . ')\}/',
            array($this, 'tagdata_callback'), $tagdata);
        $this->return_data = $tagdata;
    }
}

private function tagdata_callback($matches) {
    $method = $matches[1];
    return $this->$method();
}
```

### Caveats:

- This can make for messier templates.
- Maintaining a list of public methods apparently requires `Reflection` which is not available in PHP 4. You can, of course, maintain a list of expected methods manually.

Comment: The mess with this is to use a plugin for this behavior. Instead of forcing plugins to behave less cumbersome-yet-simple way, you can create a module for your purposes

Answer (score 2):

Interesting approach. However, this can be achieved more simply like this:

```
{exp:plugin1:method arg="{exp:plugin2:method}" parse="inward"}
```

Comment: This is not the case, as plugin1 can be an already defined plugin, out of your reach to be edited, while you are the owned/coder of plugin2. At least that's what I think, as I am at the very same situation